# how to save and retrieve Indic text(Hindi,marathi etc) in firebase real time database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a Hindi to English dictionary and I am saving Hindi font words in firebase.The Hindi font will be the key and the English word will be the value.It is getting saved properly but when I try to retrieve by doing a search using the Hindi font word I am unable to receive the word meaning as the stored Hindi(key) word is not getting searched and it does not return value when click on Search button.

```
searchWordsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(inputHindiWord.getText().toString())){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter A Word to Search",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
DatabaseReference mPostDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("synonymP");
mPostDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
searchWord = inputHindiWord.getText().toString();
if (dataSnapshot.child(searchWord).exists()){
   engWordTextView.setText(dataSnapshot.child(searchWord).getValue().toString());                             
}else{
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Such word found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                           
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Firebase stores strings as Unicode, so there should be no encoding problems. Can you reproduce the problem with a snippet that requires no user input, so that I can run it? So just give a single snippet that first writes a hard-coded string, and that then searches for that string (and can't find it).

Comment: I am directly writing it in firebase manually and then trying to retrieve it using the above code where I type the search string i.e. the Hindi(key) in the app simulator and press submit button and after that the value attached to that key should be displayed in a TextView.Since it is a dictionary app there won't be any scenario where the user will input data in database.

Comment: Since it's unlikely I can simulate your manual input, can you provide a single, standalone code snippet that we can run to reproduce the problem? It may not be what you need in your app, but it's what we need to be able to help you. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on the how and why of such so-called MCVEs.